# Spectral projection at $\{0\}$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $x$ be a positive operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H.$ Let $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ be a spectral projection of $x$. Is it true that  $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is the orthogonal projection onto closure or range of $x$?

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: What is the proof? I can show that closure of range of $x$ is contained in range of (0,∞)()? How to show the converse?

Comment: @A beginner mathematician If $e$ is the range projection, show that $\chi_{(0, \infty)}(x)e = \chi_{(0, \infty)}(x)$ and then take adjoints to see the other inclusion.

Comment: @J.De Ro. If $e$ is a range projection. We have by functional calculus $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)x=x$. This is because $t\chi_{(0,\infty)}(t)+t\chi_{\{0\}}(t)=t$ and $t\chi_{\{0\}}(t)=0$Therefore, $e\leq \chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ and $e\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)=e.$ I cannot get what you say.

Comment: @A beginner mathmatician You have $xe =x$. This implies $f(x)e = f(x)$ for every Borel $f$ with $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the range projection of $x$ and $p=\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$. Since $rx=x$, it follows that $rf(x)=f(x)$, first for polynomials, then for continuous functions, and then for Borel functions. So $rp=p$. We also have $px=x$ (from $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(t)\,t=t$ on $\sigma (x)$). So $px\xi=x\xi$ for all $\xi\in H$, which means that $pr=r$. Then
$$
p=p^*=(rp)^*=pr=r.
$$